# Run Intellij static analysis tools from the command line

Tags: intellij-idea, static-analysis

I've heard IntelliJ has really good static analysis tools for detecting dead code, improperly initialized variables, etc. However I don't really want the editor baggage, so I was looking for a way to run IntelliJ's static analysis tools on my source code right from the command line.

Is this possible? Is there an interface for running IntelliJ's static analysis tools from the command line?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it's possible to [run code inspections outside of the IDE](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/running-inspections-offline.html). You can also consider using [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) product that will do it automatically and will generate nice HTML reports that can be viewed in the browser.

Comment: I have gone through the link you provided. It seems to be a promising one. I am using Mac as my TeamCity server. I tried the command in the link. But I do not have `Default.xml`. Can you please specify what are values to be replaced in the command `/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin/inspect.sh ~/IntelliJ IDEAProjects/MyTestProject
~/Library/Preferences/ideaXX/inspection/Default.xml ~/IntelliJ IDEAProjects/MyTestProject/results-dir -v2`

Comment: I successfully built the `gradle based android studio` project in `TeamCity`. I tried a build step `Inspections (IntelliJ IDEA)`.
Project file type: `gradle`.
 Path to the project:`build.gradle` releative to checkout directory. 
 JVM command line parameters: `-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=150m`.
 But there is no `ipr` file in my project to give in `Inspection profile path: `.
I have a `.idea` directory. Please help me out ..

Comment: Please contact TeamCity support for help.